# AngularJS $http.put PUT Method not sending Data

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, put, http-method

I'm switching from jquery $.ajax, which was working fine, to using AngularJS $http.put to access a restful API.

I can make an API call, but the PUT data isn't getting sent - so my API sees a PUT request with an empty data object, which should contain a JSON string -> `data.values = 'a json structure'`

```
$http.put(
    $rootScope.api_url,
        {
            values: jsonifiedValues
        },
        {
        headers: {
            apihash: sha256hash
        }
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        // handle success
}).error(function(data,status,headers,config) {
        // handle failure
});
```

I've not used AngularJS's $http before, but when I dump out the data in my PHP api it's just empty. this is how I'm pulling it from the request in the PHP:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);  
$arr_req_data = $put_vars['values'];
```

In my API if the apihash sent from the request doesn't match the sha256 hash built on the PUT values, it fails.

This is working in JQuery, just failing now I've switched to $http. I'm not sure why the PUT data seems to be empty.

Comment: Have you looked at what the browser is actually sending using your browser's devtools?

Comment: Good point, I hadn't checked it but the data was being sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `file_get_contents('php://input')` will be a JSON string (provided everything got sent), so [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php) is not the right function to handle that data.
Instead use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php).

Also there is no need to send *jsonified values*, it will just make things more complicated as you'll have to use `json_decode` twice.

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks. Not sure why jQuery was working when AngularJS wasn't though. The AJAX methods look so simialr

Comment: @Skeater I'd say you used jQuerys `.serialize` which would work with `parse_str` as it produces the right format.

Comment: is there any way to get `$http.put` to not send a json object, and send the correctly formatted object?